# Правильная иерархическая структура в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Какой наиболее красивый и удобный способ создания в MySQL вложенной иерархической структуры, ну, самый простой пример - базовый каталог объявлений. Есть категории, они могут быть одна в другой (подкатегории).
Я использую таблицу с категориями, в которой есть id категории и id категории-родителя (для корневых - 0). Это убого? Если да, то скажите, как нормально сделать это, иначе подскажите, как при такой системе можно по человечески посчитать кол-во записей из другой таблицы, "принадлежащей" какой-либо категории (то есть не только чисто ей, это элементарно, а и всем вложенным).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL - реляционная СУБД, хранение иерархических данных в "красивом" виде в ней невозможно, так что ваш вариант является не только приемлемым, но и вполне правильным. Запросы к такой структуре в чистом виде в MySQL невозможны, но можно написать хранимую процедуру, рекурсивно вытаскивающую id-шники объявлений нужной категории и всех её подкатегорий. [Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/43955/) есть статья на эту тему. Вытащив id-шники, посчитать их не составит труда.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сейчас буду читать статью. Ибо, как я понял, адекватно сделать это через MySQL просто (без процедур, как я до этого делал) или через PHP нельзя, если уровень вложенности больше хотя бы 3-ёх.

Comment: Хм, там же в статье сказано, что в MySQL это средствами СУБД сделать нельзя, только внешне (типа PHP), а всё про Oracle расписано.

Comment: Пардон, не та ссылка. [Здесь][1] по MySQL.    

[1] http://club.shelek.ru/viewart.php?id=307

Comment: @fori1ton, я уже сам нагуглил эту статью, читаю, но всё равно спасибо, через первую статью я понял, что это надо искать как "иерархические запросы", а до этого не мог сам нагуглить.